# Have a print method in a print statement in python

Tags: python, printing

I have the following piece of code in Python which tries to put a function that prints something in a print statement.

```
def my_print(num: int) -> None:
    for i in range(num):
        print(i, end=' ')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('When num is 5 :', my_print(5))
```

I expect to get something like

```
When num is 5 : 0 1 2 3 4
```

But I actually get

```
0 1 2 3 4 When num is 5 : None
```

Could someone please explain the logic behind the print function in this case and where that *None* comes from at the end? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def my_print(num: int) -> None:
    for i in range(num):
        print(i, end=' ')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('When num is 5 :', end=" ")
    my_print(5)
```

The `None` was printing because your `my_print()` function would return a None to the calling position.

Answer (score 1):

You can try list comprehension as an alternative

```
def my_print(num: int) -> str:
    return ' '.join(map(str, [i for i in range(num)]))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(f'When num is 5 : {my_print(5)}')
```

output

```
When num is 5 : 0 1 2 3 4
```